# Trying to replace a number in text file using regex to find the right line in Python

Tags: python, regex, replace, python-3.4

I am trying to find this explicit sub-string of a specific line in a text file '***"swp_pt", "3"***' with the double-quotes and all.  I want to change the number to any other number, but I need specifically to go to the **first integer** after the quoted **swp_pt** variable and change it only.  I am still just trying to find the correct **swp_pt** call in the text file and have not been able to do even that yet.

Here is my code so far:

```
ddsFile = open('Product_FD_TD_SI_s8p.dds')
for line in ddsFile:
    print(line)
    marker = re.search('("swp_pt", ")[0-9]+', line)
print(marker)
print(marker.group())
ddsFile.close()
```

If anyone has a clue how to do this, I would very much appreciate your help.
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to do this in Python? [`sed -i`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed) will do what you want and is considerably simpler.

But if you need it, I would do something like:

```
def replace_swp_pt(line):
  regex = r'"swp_pt", "(\d+)"'
  replacement = '"swp_pt", "4"'
  return re.sub(regex, replacement, line)

def transform_file(file_name, transform_line_func):
  with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    # Buffer full contents in memory. This only works if your file
    # fits in memory; otherwise you will need to use a temporary file.
    file_contents = f.read()

  with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    for line in file_contents.split('\n'):
      transformed_line = transform_line_func(line)
      f.write(transformed_line + '\n')

  if __name__ == '__main__':
    transform_file('Product_FD_TD_SI_s8p.dds', replace_swp_pt)
```